# Which different UI versions exist in Firefox 64 64-bit? (in regard to update options)

Tags: firefox, user-interface, version, documentation, bugzilla

My Firefox 64.0 64-bit is running on Windows 7 Home Premium, both set to German language.

To find a way to stop the update nag screen I started a question (which might soon get deleted), and the people answering simply seem to have another UI than me!

**So, which different UI versions do exist in regard to the update options?** (preferably in Firefox 64.0, or if you have *the knowledge* the really occured changes for younger versions)

**Specifically** **I have no option to turn of a "Mozilla Maintenace Service" in my UI.** (In fact I'm 99,99%  sure there is no such service on my Windows system. Likely I deselected that option when installing it, or I wasn't asked when updating.)

Feel free to link to any Mozilla help page for this: At least I only found help pages, whose solutions didn't work or were outdated.

I'm already anxious to see especially the answers of those who downvote. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mozilla Maintenance Service is optional and may have not been installed with
Firefox. To install it, use the installation file `maintenanceservice_installer.exe`
found either in the folder
`C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox` or
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\`, or in both.
Or you may reinstall Firefox.

This service should by default be set to install updates automatically without
prompt/nag. But check the setting of "Use a background service to install updates"
in *Options > Preferences > Advanced > Update* and in
*Options > Preferences > General*.

Comment: Ty for the answer. That confirms what I suspected and remembered from quite a lot time ago. - (And sadly confirms the low quality of most answers on my other question, where the comments of three people just missed the point and those comments and one answer were just outdated.)

Comment: @John - Don’t confuse commentary with actual answers.  Your other question received 2 answers, one which you accepted, and one additional answer.